# Can't configure WCF Restful/json endpoints correctly

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf-binding

I created a restful service and was able to have it generate a JSON response when receiving XML requests, but I needed it to accept JSON requests.  I tweaked the processes but had issues because I originally had the main service invoking multiple services, each with its own C# interface. It told me I had to explicitly name the endpoints and it all went to the trash heap after that. I finally gave up on calling multiple services and instead went to a single service with multiple operations contracts calling methods.

Now I just get a simple "endpoint not found" message. I really, really don't understand the ins and outs of the endpoint definitions.

Here is the code on my main service page (AgtDash.svc). We're calling up statistics for an "agent dashboard"

EDIT - updated the code to reflect the URI template reference, which made no change, and changing the service name reference in the web.config. Now the error is no longer "endpoint not found", but a 404 reference, instead.

```
namespace AgentDashboard
{

    public class AgtDash : dashboardInfo
    {

        public string GetAgencyInfo(agcInfoInput agcInput)
        {
            string agInfo = string.Empty;

            (RETRIEVES DATA TABLE)

            agInfo = tableToJson(agcTable);
            return agInfo;
        }

        public string GetAgencyDetails(agcInfoInput agcInput)
        {
            string agcyInfo = string.Empty;

            (RETRIEVES DATA TABLE)

            agcyInfo = tableToJson(agcTable);
            return agcyInfo;
        }

        public string GetAgencyTotals(agcInfoInput agcInput)
        {
            string agcyTot = string.Empty;

            (RETRIEVES DATA TABLE)

            agcyTot = tableToJson(agcTable);
            return agcyTot;
        }

        public string GetAgentTotals(agtInfoInput agtInput)
        {
            (RETRIEVES DATA TABLE)

                agtInfo = tableToJson(agTable);
            return agtInfo;
        }

        public string tableToJson(DataTable inpTable)
        {
            var jsString = new StringBuilder();

            (CONVERTS DATA TABLE TO JSON RESPONSE)

            return jsString.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
namespace AgentDashboard
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface dashboardInfo
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetAgentTotals",
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetAgentTotals(agtInfoInput agentInput);

        [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetAgencyInfo",
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetAgencyInfo(agcInfoInput agencyInput);

        [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetAgencyDetails",
        Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetAgencyDetails(agcInfoInput agencyInput);

        [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetAgentTotals",
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

        string GetAgencyTotals(agcInfoInput agencyInput);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class agtInfoInput
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int year { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class agcInfoInput
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int year { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AgentDashboard.dashboardInfo" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="AgentDashboard.AgtDash">
        <endpoint address="dashboardInfo" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="AgentDashboard.dashboardInfo" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="AgtDash.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>       
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm sure that web.config is a random mess. When do I need to define the service, with endpoint details? When do I use the client configuration? When do I use both?  It seemed to be working locally okay when I originally had multiple client endpoints, but when it told me I had to define the service, I went that route.

Sorry if there are answers out there, but they are all very different in the solutions and don't offer me much insight into the whys. Ultimately, this is going to reside in its own web application/directory, being served by IIS, and needs to receive and send JSON. The generation of the JSON response seems to be working, it's getting the endpoints identified correctly that is stopping me from fully testing this because I can't correctly identify the target, so to speak.

If anything about the web.config jumps out at you, let me know. Thanks in advance.

CURRENT ERROR:

[image: 404ErrorCapture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define extra service endpoints. Based on your configuration, the operation/methods should be in the following form.

```
Http://host:portnumber/AgtDash.svc/dashboardInfo/GetAgentTotals
Http://host:portnumber/AgtDash.svc/dashboardInfo/GetAgentInfo
Http://host:portnumber/AgtDash.svc/dashboardInfo/GetAgencyDetails   
Http://host:portnumber/AgtDash.svc/dashboardInfo/GetAgencyTotals.
```

When being called, we should attach parameter in the Body section, with `Post` Http verb.
The service base configured in the `Webconfig` could be ignored. It is determined by the IIS site binding.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
replace `<service name="AgentDashboard.AgentDashInfo">` with `<service name=”AgentDashboard.AgtDash”>`. Here the implemented class with namespace should be configured.

Comment: But when I try to run the service on localhost, I get error messages that it can't find the endpoint, or that no endpoint is defined. You are telling me that I don't need to define service endpoints, but the program won't run and it tells me that it has to find them.

Comment: Can you access the SVC page properly? Http://host:portnumber/AgtDash.svc  . try to replace <service name="AgentDashboard.AgentDashInfo">  with <service name=”AgentDashboard.AgtDash”>
Here the implemented class with namespace should be configured.

Comment: rebuild the project so as to find the service class implements the service interface.

Comment: Sorry, my response got lost somewhere. No, I can't access the SVC page properly. That's what causes my errors.  Changing the service name resolved the "endpoint not found" problem. Thank you. Now I get a "404" message. I updated the original post to reflect the current status of the code and the error message. Can I or should I remove the "client" configuration information?  Is the "host" configuration tag within the service definition an issue? Can I drop that?  Is my "contract" reference in the endpoint correct?

Comment: There was a "Factory" reference in the .asp markup that needed to be removed. The service is now loading.

Comment: Cheers, "Factory" is used to perform some other operation when starting the service. we need to implement it separately.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/extending-hosting-using-servicehostfactory.  if you don't mind, please mark it as an answer, I need that. (^.^)

Comment: Also - was able to put it onto the web server and then invoke it in the SOAPUI tester.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the UriTemplate like this:

```
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetAgentTotals",
      Method = "POST",
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

      string GetAgentTotals(agtInfoInput agentInput)
```

Notice the UriTemplate with the name of the method.

This will help the client find the correct operation mapping.

When I do webHttpBinding I usually have to add the UriTemplate.

**FINAL NOTES:**

For transforming existing WCF to support json that is fine... But for new services I would just use ASP.NET Core.  It has much better support for JSON and many other features.

Specially if all you need is HTTP.

Comment: #1 - I did have the URI template, exactly like that, and it gave the the same error messages. The problem isn't that the client can't find the endpoint, it's that when I try to run the solution I get that error message when I try to load/run the AgentDash.svc page. It brings up a web page that says "SERVICE" in a banner on top of the page with a message in the body that says "can't find end point."  #2 - I'm building the service to the specification of the client that is invoking it, so I don't get to choose, unfortunately.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet then we need to see the entire error message and screenshots. Also the code you posted has no UriTemplate on the operations. So it is confusing to know your exact problem.. I think you also need to update your code on the question to reflect the reality of your code.  Otherwise how can we find the problem?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet even better if you can post a minumum reproducible example even better.

Comment: My example didn't have the URI templates because I decided to remove stuff I had added along the way. What I said was that I did have it in there, **previously**, and the message was the same. I just added it back and it makes no difference.  You DID see the entire error message. There was a banner at the top of the web page that said "SERVICE" and it said "END POINT NOT FOUND" on the body of the page, that was it.  Abraham's advice, I placed the service name, and now I get a 404 error message. In my comment, below, that IS the entirety of the message.  I HAVE posted exactly what my code.

Comment: And, yeah, it's confusing to know the exact problem. That's why I'm posting the question.

Comment: I'm not posting the whole program with the full functions because there's nothing, at all, about the functions that isn't working. It's either in the contract specifications, or the web.config.

Comment: Got it working. I had to remove a reference in the .svc markup that I added based on looking at previous Q and A on this site - a "FACTORY" reference.

Comment: Thanks for the very speedy help on this.